# rails3 - Model Naming Suggestion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting ready to add notification settings to my app. Allowing a user to select true/false, for which type of activities they want notifications for.

My idea for a model is: **UserSettingsNotifications**. I picked UserSettings, as it's tied to the User, and the user will have several setting types including notifications and others.

Something like:

```
rails generate model UserSettingNotifications CommentReply:boolean .....
```

What do you think? Good to go, or not- rails friendly?

Comment: Shouldn't model classes be singular? ex : UserSettingNotification. Atleast that's what I think is Rails convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You phrased it "notification settings". I suggest dropping the user prefix and naming it NotificationSettings since it's likely clear in the model it belongs_to :user

Comment: Interesting. But then if a I have lets say BillingSettings. all the user settings are not grouped together. Seems un clean? no?